# How to decode base64 attachment file - Gmail API

Tags: javascript, php, base64, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API function in javascript:

```
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
  'userId': 'me',
  'messageId': 'MyMessageId',
  'id': 'MyAttachmentId'
});

request.execute(function(resp) {
  var dd = new FormData();
  //here resp.result.data is the base64 data of the attachment file
  dd.append( "img_data", JSON.stringify( resp.result.data ) );

  fetch("http://my-url",{
    method: 'post',
    body: dd
  });
}
```

I am sending this data to a url, where the server code is done using php.
I am using the following code to decode the base64 data and to save the file(Just for png image files):

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', './');
$img = json_decode($_POST['img_data']);
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Everything works fine, but the saved image file is corrupted and shows the error: `Fatal error reading PNG image file: Decompression error in IDAT`

Comment: Not quite sure of that, but shouldn't whitespaces be removed altogether rather than replaced with '+' signs?

Comment: I have tried to decode it without replacing the whitespaces. But getting the same error

Comment: Also tried 
`$data = base64_decode(chunk_split($img));`

Comment: If you're under Linux, can you try `cmp -l original.png uploaded.png`? (Or maybe a tool like WinMerge under Windows.)

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I got the output `cmp: EOF on uploaded.png`

Comment: Hmm ... so it seems like your uploaded file is somehow truncated. I assume you tried that without chunk_split() and without replacing the whitespaces?

Comment: Yes I have tried both

Comment: Mind to try with a very small picture, just to see if we're hitting some limit?

Comment: Tried an image with size 34kb. Still the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution. Added the following php code:

```
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$img = str_replace('_', '/', $img);
$img = str_replace('-', '+', $img);
```

The new code to decode and to save the file:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', './');

$img = json_decode($_POST['img_data']);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$img = str_replace('_', '/', $img);
$img = str_replace('-', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```